# how to count consecutive occurences of substring in string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing an exercise ([cs50 - DNA](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/6/dna/)) where I have to count specific consecutive substrings (STRS) mimicking DNA sequences, I'm finding myself overcomplicating my code and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to proceed.

I have a list of substrings:

`strs = ['AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC']`

And a String with a random sequence of letters:

`AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG`

I want to count the biggest consecutive substrings that match each strs.

So:

- `'AGATC'` - AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGG**AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC**TATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG
- `'AATG'` - AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATT**AATG**GAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG
- `'TATC'` - AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC**TATCTATCTATCTATCTATC**AGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG

resulting in `[4, 1, 5]`

I know that I should be something of the likes of `re.match(rf"({strs}){2,}", string)` because `str.count(strs)` will give me still I'm not sure how to count only the consecutive substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you are not supposed using REGEX**, you can use forloops

```
for x in your_sbstr_list:
    print(your_string.count(x))
```

full code would be

```
STRS = ["AGATC", "TTTTTTCT", "AATG", "TCTAG", "GATA", "TATC", "GAAA", "TCTG"]
s = "AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG"

for x in STRS:
    print(f"{x} : {s.count(x)}")
```

Comment: but how to count just the consecutives?